# Lock a file for a child process

Tags: c#, windows, process

I'm working on a project to execute jar from an exe file but to lock it while being executed. While the jar file is being executed the user is not allowed to open the file for reading/writing/executing. 
I have the following code in C#

```
Process process = new Process();
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
var stinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
stinfo.FileName = "javaw.exe";

stinfo.Arguments = "-jar \"" + filePath + "\" " + argument;
stinfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
stinfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
stinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
stinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo = stinfo;

process.Start();

StreamReader rd = process.StandardOutput;
StreamReader rdError = process.StandardError;
String output = rd.ReadToEnd();
```

The code executes well but there is no way for me to lock the file for the new child process and if I lock for the parent process it wont allow the child to access. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: @eryksun yes, I only want to lock for the child process.

Comment: i suppose after you execute it, you could take an exclusive read write lock on it, however i am not sure how jar files work whether they are continually accessed by the javaw.exe which would be a problem

Comment: @MichaelRandall Jar files are continually accessed at least until their execution is complete.